# VB.NET - Object assignment source confusion

Tags: vb.net

In my code, I have two variables, "replacedCell" and "newCell". They are both custom objects of the same type. I have them as class level variables.

When I assign replacedCell to equal a specific object from a dictionary, everything is fine. Afterwards I need to assign newCell to equal replacedCell, and then I make a change to a variable in newCell. For some reason, changing that variable in newCell also changes it in replacedCell. When I set newCell = replacedCell, I thought it would only assign newCell as what replacedCell was "currently" in that moment. How can I modify my code to get that effect?

Brief sample of the code that matters:

```
            replacedCell = currentSchedule.scheduleCellDict.Item(cell)
            currentSchedule.scheduleCellDict.Remove(cell)
            newCell = replacedCell
            newCell.name = mainForm.cboName.Text
            currentSchedule.scheduleCellDict.Add(cell, newCell)
```

Comment: If you change (ie. mutate) *an* object, you change *that* object - by *any* and *all* names (ie. variables) it is known by. The assignment operator in VB.NET does *not* create a copy/clone/duplicate of a reference type value.

Comment: Objects are reference types.  `replacedCell` just points to some data representing whatever it is.  `newCell = replacedCell` means they now both point to the same data.  Changing one changes both.  If you just want to use `replacedCell` as a starting point for new `newCell`, clone it or use a copy constructor